# Angular 12 optimized build fails with not much to go on

Tags: angular

My project builds fine in dev mode with the build optimizer set to false but on production build I get this error:

```
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
✔ ES5 bundle generation complete.
✔ Copying assets complete.
✖ Index html generation failed.
undefined:9:113354: property missing ':'
```

I have gone over every dependency and can't see anything wrong.  This is a very large project so without knowing which file or even which component is causing issue it feels impossible to debug.

How can I get to what error is stopping the build from running?

Comment: Can you please add your `angularCompilerOptions` from the tsconfig.json?

Answer (score 0):

To fix it I needed to add this to my build config:

```
"optimization": {
    "scripts": true,
    "styles": {
      "minify": true,
      "inlineCritical": false
    },
    "fonts": true
  }
```

Full issue: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/20760